# need topological map online, graph_slam doesn't work

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, mapping, graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anybody had success using the graph_slam package described at
http://www.ros.org/wiki/graph_slam
I tried checking out the source and building it but the dependencies do not build.

Or do you have any suggestions how I can build a topological map out of a SLAM gridmap fairly efficiently on the fly?

Edit: I am using the cturtle-pr2all stack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9600/need-topological-map-online,-graph_slam-doesn%27t-work/) by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 535 on 2011-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-03-30**:
CTurtle, sorry about that

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-29**:
Could you include which release (CTurtle or Diamondback) you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't see this question till now, unfortunately.  If you still need this, you can check out the new version of the topological_navigation stack (see [www.ros.org/wiki/topological_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/topological_navigation) for instructions).  In particular, the topological_map_2d package defines the topological map type and the laser_slam_mapper package constructs a node that constructs it.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1